# Активировать код на нажатие клавиши

Tags: java

То есть надо сделать так, чтоб вместо ожидания 15 секунд, было ожидание нажатия определенной клавиши. Например я запускаю программу, наживаю допустим ALT или любую другую кнопку, и начинает работать программа.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ddd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException
    {

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15); // ожидание 10 секунд после начала, чтоб ввести данные


        Color [] colALL = new Color[5]; // создание переменных пикселей

        Robot rC = new Robot();
        Color colUN = rC.getPixelColor(960, 540);

        colALL[1] = rC.getPixelColor(959, 539);
        colALL[2] = rC.getPixelColor(959, 541);
        colALL[3] = rC.getPixelColor(961, 539);
        colALL[4] = rC.getPixelColor(959, 541);

        while (true) // бесконечный цикл
        {
            screenWork(colALL, colUN);
        }
    }

    public static void screenWork(Color[] colALL, Color colUN) throws AWTException, InterruptedException // сравнение цветов
    {
        Robot rR = new Robot();
        if (rR.getPixelColor(959, 539).equals(colALL[1]) && rR.getPixelColor(959, 541).equals(colALL[2]) && rR.getPixelColor(961, 539).equals(colALL[3]) && rR.getPixelColor(959, 541).equals(colALL[4])) // нажатие лкм
        {
        }
        else
        {
            clicker();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
        }
    }

    public static void clicker() throws AWTException // функция ЛКМ
    {
        Robot rC = new Robot(); // robotClicker
        rC.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        rC.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ddd {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException
{

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String f = s.nextLine();
    if(f.equals("$") { //если нажат доллар + Enter

    Color [] colALL = new Color[5]; // создание переменных пикселей

........
}
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что автору нужно без нажатия Enter